# Unable to have the static route on boot using systemd | Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, systemd-networkd

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, which is being run in a VMWare Fusion VM, and it is needed to have a static routes being added on boot:

1. to the network `192.168.11.0/24`, that is available via the IP `192.168.10.4`, which is on the same network with the one of the IPs, assigned to local interface (`eth0`).
2. to the network `192.168.2.0/24`, that is available via the IP `192.168.122.101`, which is on the same network with the one of the IPs, assigned to the local interface (`virbr0`)

I have configured the `10-static.network` network file, with the following, in order to accomplish it:

```
root@gns3local:~# cat /etc/systemd/network/10-static.network
[Route]
Gateway=192.168.10.5
Destination=192.168.11.0/24
root@gns3local:~# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
root@gns3local:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe3e:70a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3e:70:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 234  bytes 22886 (22.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 156  bytes 22033 (22.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:01:a3:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


root@gns3local:~# systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-27 16:52:47 UTC; 12min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 515 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 5861)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─515 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Jul 27 16:52:47 gns3local systemd-networkd[515]: virbr0-nic: Lost carrier
Jul 27 16:52:47 gns3local systemd-networkd[515]: virbr0-nic: Removing non-existent address: fe80::5054:ff:fe01:a3e5/64
Jul 27 16:52:48 gns3local systemd-networkd[515]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Jul 27 16:52:48 gns3local systemd-networkd[515]: eth0: Configured
```

Now, after the system gets rebooted, the route is not getting added, and no errors related to it:

```
root@gns3local:~# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.10.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.10.255
        inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe3e:70a6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:3e:70:a6  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 83  bytes 12321 (12.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 77  bytes 11639 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:01:a3:e5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
root@gns3local:~# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 virbr0
root@gns3local:~# systemctl status systemd-networkd
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-07-27 17:39:02 UTC; 2min 22s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
 Main PID: 539 (systemd-network)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 5860)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
           └─539 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

Jul 27 17:39:02 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: virbr0-nic: Could not set route: Network is unreachable
Jul 27 17:39:02 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: virbr0: Link UP
Jul 27 17:39:02 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: virbr0-nic: Link DOWN
Jul 27 17:39:02 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: virbr0-nic: Lost carrier
Jul 27 17:39:02 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: virbr0-nic: Removing non-existent address: fe80::5054:ff:fe01:a3e5/64
Jul 27 17:39:03 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.10.5/24 via 192.168.10.1
Jul 27 17:39:03 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Jul 27 17:39:03 gns3local systemd-networkd[539]: eth0: Configured
```

Questions:

- What could be a reason for the routes to not persist on boot?
- What is the best practise to add the static routes on boot?
- How can I add the same route using `crontab`?

Comment: In the question you say the network is reachable via `192.168.0.1`, but in the .network file you have specified `192.168.0.5` as the gateway, which is the IP address of the local host. Is that a mistake? Also, I don't see the need for the host route to `192.168.0.1`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen. You're right, in the description, there was a typo, corrected that. However, according to idea, `192.168.11.0/24` is available via `192.168.10.5`, which is local interface, and the same specified in the `10-static.network`, but, still didn't work on boot.

Comment: The .network file essentially says: "to reach network `192.168.11.0/24`, send packets to the gateway at `192.168.0.5`; it knows how to forward the packets". "Oh, wait, `192.168.0.5` is us, and we still don't know where to find `192.168.11.0/11`"  If I understand correctly, both networks (.10 and .11) are on the same interface, which is a bit unusual. Normally you would have the networks on separate NICs. In any case, you will have to add an additional address from `192.168.1.0/24` to eth0, then it knows that other hosts in that subnet can be found on the local link.